# Knapsack algorithm, weird behavior (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have been working on recursion and tried to solve the Knapsack problem [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem]. I came up with the algorithm below which works just fine:

```
cost_array = [2,3,4,5,9]
value_array = [3,4,8,8,10]

def KP(Weight, C, V):
    if Weight < 2:
        return 0
    q = 0
    for i in range(len(C)):
        q = max(q, (KP(Weight-C[i], [x for j,x in enumerate(C) if j!=i], \
                [x for j,x in enumerate(V) if j!=i]) + V[i]*(Weight-C[i] >= 0)))
    return q


print(KP(25,cost_array,value_array))
```

However when I change the value of `q` to `q < 0` and call `print(KP(25,cost_array,value_array))` the result I get is `33 - q`. With `33` being the max value the knapsack can have.

What is weird here is that I only get this behavior if I call the initial function with a `Weight > 23` and here `23=2+3+4+5+9`.

I can't figure out at what point the negative `q` gets added to my result for me this line never performs such an operation, can you guys enlighten me ?

```
q = max(q, (KP(W-C[i], [x for j,x in enumerate(C) if j!=i], [x for j,x in enumerate(V) if j!=i]) + V[i]*(W-C[i] >= 0)))
```

Thanks,

d_darric

Comment: Actually when you are assigning `q` a negative value then you are getting `33+q` not `33-q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `q=-2` (a negative value)
Therefore you are filling your base cases with `-2` . That is `-2` is returned for base cases of your function which is then getting added to the answer on each step in recursion. Try a bottom up approach with a 2D array. You can look at that here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LusJS5-AGo . In your case you are filling matrix base cases with -2.

```
def knapSack(W, wt, val, n): 
    K = [[0 for x in range(W+1)] for x in range(n+1)] 

    q=-2 #Make it zero for correct answer

    # Build table K[][] in bottom up manner 
    for i in range(n+1): 
        for w in range(W+1): 
            if i==0 or w==0: 
                K[i][w] = q #Here you are assigning negative value
            elif wt[i-1] <= w: 
                K[i][w] = max(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]],  K[i-1][w]) 
            else: 
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w] 

    return K[n][W] 

# Driver program to test above function 
value_array = [3,4,8,8,10]
cost_array =  [2,3,4,5,9]
Weight = 25
n = len(val) 
print(knapSack(Weight, cost_array, value_array, n))
```